# How to Override a classname with javascript that has hyphen in it (-)

Tags: javascript

Hello guys i want to try toggle my cart button with javascript

```
let cartIcon = document.querySelector('#cart-icon')
let cart = document.querySelector('.cart')
let cartClose = document.querySelector('#close-cart')

cartIcon.onclick = () => {
    cart.classList.add("active");
    console.log(cart)
};
cartClose.onclick = () => {
    cart.classList.remove("active");
}
```

but, when i try to console it only show "cart active" not "cart-active"
[image: Console Log]

Comment: unclear what your problem is. "cart active" is TWO classes, it is not one. If you want to replace cart with cart-active, than you need to remove "cart" and add "cart-active". Or just code your CSS to use the one class and make your life simple. `.cart.active { display: block; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you aren't doing anything to the `cart` class.

```
cartIcon.onclick = () => {
    cart.classList.remove("cart");
    cart.classList.add("cart-active");
};
cartClose.onclick = () => {
    cart.classList.remove("cart-active");
    cart.classList.add("cart");
}
```

if you want to replace the `cart` class with `cart-active`.